# How should I use PHP $_GET and variables to fill my template page with content from other files?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, syntax

I'm new to PHP and web development, and I'm trying to figure out how to design my site with as little copy-and-pasted code as possible. Essentially, I want each page to use the same layout, header menu, and footer; the only difference between each page will be the stuff inside the 'content_container'. This is a simplified version of what I'm working with right now:

```
<?php $content = htmlspecialchars($_GET["content_url"]);?>

<body>
    <div id="main_container">
        <?php require 'header.html';?>

        <div id="content_container">
            <?php include $content;?>
        </div>

        <?php require 'header.html';?>
    </div>
</body>
```

All of the site's 'content' is stored in pages (about.html, social.html, etc.) that should be somehow loaded into the 'content_container' div of the index.php 'template' page. This way, it should be easy to maintain and update the site's content without touching the template at all. Before this, I tried using AJAX to load in content asynchronously but I wasn't able to link directly to individual pages through that method, so using PHP $_GET seems like a better option.

I have a good idea of what I *want to do*, but my unfamiliarity with web development and the syntax of PHP is kind of a roadblock for me right now. So, how can I use PHP $_GET to populate my page with content from another file? **Edit 1**: Or, am I going about this problem the wrong way, and what should I be doing instead?

**Edit 2**: For the mere sake of learning, I'd kind of prefer to see how this kind of thing is done using PHP (or even JS, if possible). I know that there are probably lots of good template libraries/frameworks out there, but I want to understand how to implement these kind of things on my own if I can.

Comment: Why you wanna use content from another file? Well whatever -> You have to create a Form in order to send $_GET variables to another page. When you submit the form and your input fields, these will be sent to the action page. Just check for "HTML GET Forms" in google.

Comment: How do you want the GET method to be set? Via a form or linking it throughout the pages. Specifying **somesite.com/index.php?content_url=apple.html** would include **apple.html**. This is a security risk though, as it can be used to exploit some files that you may not want to show.

Comment: I was thinking about passing it through the URL, just like that. Hmm.. I can totally see how that might be a security risk. Is there some extra validation that I can do to make sure that it's one of my pages? Or should I be trying to populate my site with content through other methods? (I could totally be going about this problem the wrong way..) Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if I understand you you are sending a url with a GET variable like this:
`http://www.yoursite.com/?content_url=http://www.yoursite.com/pages/about.html` and your plan is that you want to fetch the url of where your file is located, and then include that files contents to your current page.

I think you missunderstand how people commonly use GET variables, and I recommend you to not proceed in the way you are currently doing it. It is bad for several reasons. It's also very bad to load all content with Ajax, because Google would not be able to index that content.

**Now to the answer:**
If you still want to use $_GET to load content into the page. I would do something like this:

Example URL: `http://www.yoursite.com/?page=about`

PHP Code:

```
<?php
    //Check if the get variable "page" is set to "about", then load about.html
    if($_GET['page'] == "about"){
        $content = file_get_contents("http://www.yoursite.com/pages/about.html");
    }
?>
```

You can read about file_get_contents here http://php.net/file_get_contents

Please note that this is not the "best" way to solve urls for websites. This is just an answer of how you can achieve what you are asking for. If you want a more advanced solution you should look into mod_rewrite and .htaccess.

Comment: Great! This looks pretty much exactly like the sort of thing that I need. This looks like it will suit my purpose just fine, but I'll look into the other methods that you suggested also. Thanks for the help, Marcus.

Comment: Yep. Worked like a charm! I simply ran the result of the $_GET through a switch statement and loaded the appropriate page's contents with 'file_get_contents()'. Way simpler than what I had in mind, and it seems to avoid the security pitfalls too. Thanks again for the help! I think I have a better understanding of PHP $_GET now.